# Form submitting information twice. How do you stop that?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This script works to clear a form on submit and fades the response in and out, but for some strange reason it is submitting the form twice. How do you get it to stop sending the information a user submits twice?

Here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var clearOnSuccess = function() {
                    if (jQuery('#emailSubmit').length > 0) {
                        jQuery('#email').val('');
                    }
                };
                clearOnSuccess();

                jQuery('#signup').submit(function() {
                    var data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
                    data.push({'name': 'ajax', 'value': 1});
                    var jqXHR = jQuery.ajax({
                        url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
                        type: jQuery(this).attr('method'),
                        data: data
                    });

                    jqXHR.done(function(data) {
                        jQuery('#response').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
                        clearOnSuccess();
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Is it one Ajax submit followed by one "normal" submit? Any errors in the console (something that might stop the function before it gets to the `return false` and thus allow the default submit behaviour to continue)?

Comment: What makes you think it's submitting the form twice?

Answer (score 2):

In your jQuery `submit()` handler you are just executing code once the form has been submitted, but then you are again AJAX'ing that data to the server, so you receive two copies.  Try using `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting and then only send the info once with the `.ajax()` call:

```
...
           jQuery('#signup').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
                data.push({'name': 'ajax', 'value': 1});
                var jqXHR = jQuery.ajax({
                    url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
                    type: jQuery(this).attr('method'),
                    data: data
                });
                ...
           });
 ...
```

Comment: @user2485157 Are you passing the `e` parameter to the function?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with jQuery. I just replaced the section of code with what you suggested. How do you pass the e parameter to the function?

Comment: Alex the OP's code has a `return false;` at the end, which should prevent the default submit.

Comment: It's for a newsletter signup. I'm testing it, and it submits the user's email address fine, but it sends it twice.